# PHP Time showing different times per page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, countdowntimer

I have three different pages using the same code to get the time for a countdown clock.  The clock counts down to midnight.

The second and third pages are showing the same time counting down, but the homepage is showing a different time.  It's all the same code and I included this PHP files on each of the pages:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
        serverDate: {
            'day':      <?php echo date("j"); ?>,
            'month':    <?php echo date("n"); ?>,
            'year':     <?php echo date("Y"); ?>,
            'hour':     24,
            'min':      0,
            'sec':      0,
            'serverDay':    <?php echo date("j"); ?>,
            'serverMonth':  <?php echo date("n"); ?>,
            'serverYear':   <?php echo date("Y"); ?>,
            'serverHour':   <?php echo date("G"); ?>,
            'serverMin':    <?php echo date("i"); ?>,
            'serverSec':    <?php echo date("s"); ?>
        },
        omitWeeks: true
    });
});
</script>
```

What do I need to change to make the homepage timer match up with the others?

Comment: 3.1 out of 5 for SO? I thought it had pretty good SEO — how else did all of our questions make it to the first result on Google?

Comment: That part isn't actually integrated into their rating system yet - it's just there as a placeholder but should be integrated in to use their actual ratings by tomorrow (hopefully).  SO I'm sure has a great rating, basically everything on it gets indexed within minutes ;)

Comment: Are they all getting served from the same server? Looks like a time zone difference to me.

Comment: I tried that url with a few different domain names in place of SO, I got some random results different from both the homepage and SO. Also envisionforce.com only gets a 2.8 so SO has it beat.

Comment: putting cloud-flare infront of a page that you want to not be cached is an interesting choice. why don't you make the counter js based? The page doesn't need any server-side logic, if the js timer is js-only, you don't need it either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the homepage is providing a time that is +4 hours off from the other two links you provided. This would indicate to me that the homepage script is using a different timezone setting than the other two links.

PHP has an [internal timezone setting](http://php.net/date.timezone) called `date.timezone` that is affected by php.ini and can be changed at run-time with the [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) function. Most of PHP's date/time functions like the one you're using [date](http://php.net/date), are affected by this timezone setting.

You can add a call to [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo) in each of those scripts, and it will output all of the loaded configuration directives for those scripts and that can help you figure out which [timezone](http://php.net/timezones) is currently being used for each one. Note that if the timezone is left blank different versions of PHP behave differently. Older versions of PHP (pre PHP 5.4) used to try and guess your system's timezone setting, whereas in PHP 5.4+ it will just default to UTC.

Comment: Followed up on this a bit more and ended up adding this code to the PHP file which fixed it:  `date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');`